# Adding a predefined cell style in ClosedXml

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, closedxml

Excel comes with a number of predefined cell styles such as *Good*, *Note* and *Heading 3*, as shown in the *Cell Styles* popup below.

[image]

Is there a way to assign these cell styles to a range of cells in [ClosedXML](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML)?